# Linking a resource via CDN in Razor Pages results in Error RZ1005

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I am building an application using ASP.NET Razor Pages. I want to use Tailwind CSS in my application, so I used Tailwind's CDN in my _Layout.cshtml file, but I am getting an error.

Tailwind CDN URL:

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet" />
```

Error:

> RZ1005    "^" is not valid at the start of a code block. Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.
> E:\MXN\CODE\Razor pages\Razor pages\Pages\Shared_Layout.cshtml   10

My _Layout.cshtml file code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Razor_pages</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    @RenderSection("Styles", false)
     <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet" />
    @*<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Razor_pages.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />*@
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Razor_pages</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Login">Login</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Signup">Signup</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2022 - Razor_pages - <a asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Razor markup starts with the `@` symbol. With `@`, you can use C# variable or code in the view. If you want to use @ in href, try to use `@@`:

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@@^2.2.7/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

result:
[image]